# Preventing users manipulate on the page after submit on another tab of browser (asp.net)

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to write the method to prevent users click button if the page was submitted, like this way:

1. user visit the page 1
2. he open the page 1 in another tab (tab 2) of browser
3. he click submit or logout or any change in the page 1
4. when he goes to page 1 in tab 2, it will show something like a notification or force to reload page..

Any solution guys? Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

I have used this in the past

`$(window).focusout(function({$(window).focusin(function({$(window).off('focusout');location.reload();})});`

This in pretty basic and not ideal for every use case, as it will always force a refresh whenever a user loses / gains focus of the window.
You could save some information to local storage in the browser to save/check if the user performed a submit on a page and then only reload the page if it was submitted.